# Form a html_safe string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, html-safe

```
link_to "hi",content_tag(:p,"hello")
```

produces me 
`"<a href=\"&lt;p&gt;hello&lt;/p&gt;\">hi</a>"` 
i don't want the escaped output. how to get a html_safe string?

Comment: You cannot/should not use html tags in the `href` attribute...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reversed arguments order - see http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Correct syntax is `link_to content, url` so what you probably wanted to do is:

`link_to content_tag(:p, "hello"), "some_url"`

This will not be escaped. If what you need is indeed content_tag as url then you can add "html_safe" method at the end:

`link_to "hi",content_tag(:p,"hello").html_safe`

Comment: if you  add html_safe at the end you get the same result